# Prove Uniform Convergence of Sequence of Functions Fails

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am trying to prove that the following sequence of functions does not converge uniformly on $0\leq x <1$

$f_n(x)=nx^n$

The problem is probably at x=0 but I'm not sure how to show this

Comment: Near $x=1$, too, something is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The problem is at the other end, near $x=1$. Consider evaluating $f_n(x)$ at $x=1-\frac1n$, and remember the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n=e^{-1}.$$
Multiplying the whole thing by $n$ just makes it worse.

Comment: This interval doesn't include 1 though

Comment: @jmars The value $1-\frac1n$ lives within the interval $0\le x<1$.